# A croupier at a casino said "500 euros la partie". Is it shorthand for "500 euros par partie"?

Tags: usage, articles, nombres

I'm currently in France for my summer holidays, and today when I sat down at a roulette table at a casino, I heard a croupier say:

> Envie de faire tourner la roulette et de miser gros, peut-être ? 500 euros **la partie**.

I gathered she meant something like:

> À noter que le montant de mise minimum est de 500 euros **par partie** sur cette table de roulette pour les high rollers.

I'm wondering if the definite article "***la*** (partie)" is commonly used like this, perhaps as shorthand for "***par*** (partie)", even if it might be a casino-specific term?

Comment: Je ne saurais dire en quel casino vous vous trouvez. Mais... à ma connaissance... à la **roulette**, dans aucun casino du monde, il n'est question de *partie* et encore moins de *montant à la partie*. À la roulette ce sont des montants minimums de pari sur un jeu simple qui sont assignés, par table et pour toute la durée d'ouverture de la table. (Le montant maximum est aussi fixé de fait car étant un multiple du minimum, ceci afin d'éviter les d'Alembert)

Comment: Au demeurant, rien de ces montants n'est à la discrétion du croupier.

Comment: @aCOSwt Once again, I don't follow the gist of your comment, especially what you mean by "il n'est question de *partie*". Because it IS. I wonder ... do you have a solid grasp on how bets are placed on a roulette table? Perhaps, "*le montant de mise*" is not a layman's term, but it's used when you literally *hedge* your bets, that is, when you place bets on multiple numbers. Roulette is not just about picking one number.

Comment: partie de roulette. http://roulette77.fr/comment-jouer

Comment: @aCOSwt Je ne fréquente pas les casinos mais tous les sites de casinos que je viens de consulter  (ex :https://www.casino-annecy.com/roulette-anglaise-1171) parlent de **partie** de roulette.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it means 500€ for one game.

It is not a dedicated usage specialized for casinos. We say prices like this.

In the supermarkets we say:

- "4 € le kilo de tomates"

And on the market place, it would be common (if not always) to hear prices announced like this:

- "2 euros le sac de pomme de terre! Deux euros! Qui veut de mes belles pommes de terre ? Allez soyez pas timides !"

Comment: Ah, so it's a structure preferred in ads and whatnot -- perhaps, for the sake of conciseness? By the way, can you see what aCOSwt is trying to say in the comment above?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens his comment is for expert at Roulette ;-): I had not noticed/understood at first reading, but since you asked me so I've re-read it. When you play Roulette, there's no minimum price to pay for one game: you bet the amount that you want on the color, number, group of numbers (there are multiple places where you can place your bet). So he is explaining your sentence may be a bit not in good context, not the good game. That would be fine for many other game though, so that's fine for me.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens I would not say it is for conciseness sake. I have tried to think (during less than a minute) about another way to say prices and I've come up with no other way than : 'prix' followed by 'la quantité de' and the product/thing/stuff . It's like a pair, a tuple in computer science.

Comment: Perhaps, he didn't notice the "*pour les high rollers*" bit  in my description, then. The table I sat down at was reserved specifically for high rollers, and as such, the total amount of money (or its equivalent in casino tokens) that you bet per *spin* had to exceed 500 euros.

Comment: Ok, during my stay in France, I'll be on the lookout for such signs in stores. :D

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens It took me sometime to remember another way of saying this: We can also say "le prix au kilo" like in "les noix, 15€ au kilo".